# Is a parcelable transmitted via LocalBroadcastManager immutable?

Tags: android, serialization, immutability, broadcast, parcelable

If I send a Parcelable object to another part of my program via LocalBroadcastManager -is the Parcelable immutable then? Immutable in the sense that the received Parcelable cant affect the object that was originally transmitted. I would guess so, because I guess Parcelable is a "deepcopy" serialization mechanism and not pass by reference, but I need to be sure. Can someone who knows, tell me if I have to worry about someone in the receiving end changing values on the received object, if I want to prevent that from affecting the original object...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I send a Parcelable object to another part of my program via LocalBroadcastManager -is the Parcelable immutable then?

That is not guaranteed. In fact, AFAIK, it does not happen at all for local broadcasts.

> I guess Parcelable is a "deepcopy" serialization mechanism and not pass by reference

Only across process boundaries. That happens to include things like `startActivity()` for another one of your activities, because those involve IPC. But the `Intent` object -- and its extras -- is simply passed around your process with `LocalBroadcastManager`. I see no place where `Intent` would be forced to make a copy.

Comment: But when I implement Parcelable I have this:
#writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) { dest.writeString(myString);}
Then that must be bytified and put into Parcel dest -no? I mean does it really keep a reference back after unpack? Does it not unpack to a fresh new instance?

Comment: @user2254314: "Then that must be bytified and put into Parcel dest -no?" -- only when needed. There is nothing in `LocalBroadcastManager` that needs to convert the `Intent` into a byte array. You are welcome to review [the source code to `LocalBroadcastManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java).